# CKEditor Captioned Image(Image 2 Plugin)

Tags: ckeditor

I am using captioned image plugin in ckeditor. Where i can see caption with image. This figcaption(caption of image) have by default attribute `contenteditable="true"`. Can i remove this attribute from image2 configuration or can i make this contenteditable to false. Because on my creator i am showing by default caption of image so i am not allowing user to change default caption.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'image2';
```

I tried to found its configuration but dint get any config for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *editable* areas inside widgets (the Image2 plugin uses widgets to insert images) are defined by [editables property](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-editables) in [widget definition](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition). Image2 plugin has this [property fixed](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/plugin.js#L286) so it cannot be changed by config options.

However, it can be replaced using [widgetDefiniton event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-widgetDefinition) like this:

```
editor.on( 'widgetDefinition', function( evt ) {
    var widget = evt.data;

    if ( widget.name == 'image' ) {
        widget.editables = null;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Working fine :)